# Mac Excel 2011 - IF formatting for simple expense tracker

Tags: excel

I'm creating a simple expense tracker for my wife's business.   It's simply "money in, money out" style.

When I add an entry, here is what I'll be entering:
1)date
2)merchant
3)transaction type (income or expense)
4)amount

I've got a couple other cells namely "income" and expense", these of which will track what is happening.

What I want to happen is, based on whether the transaction type is 'income' or 'expense', I want either the 'income' or 'expense' cell to count and sum.

What does my "IF" statement need to look like?  I've tried:
=IF(=income,,) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Debit/Credit (expense/income) in separate columns and sum it up individually and then do the final balance calculation. This is usually how I do it. See Screenshot.

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to make it more fancy by keeping Income/Expense in one column then you can also use Conditional formatting and later `SumIF()` to calculate the totals. See the below screenshots

A. Select your range and create a data validation.

[image]

B. Set two conditional formatting rules as shown below

[image]

This will color the cells green or red depending on what you selected (Income/Expense)

C. Finally use the formulas to sum the Income/expense

[image]

Formulas in

D18 `=SUMIF(C2:C16,"Income",D2:D16)`

D19 `=SUMIF(C2:C16,"Expense",D2:D16)`

HTH

Comment: And in your suggestion, what if I wanted to calculate the ENTIRE C column?

Comment: You mean "D" Column in the second scenario?

Comment: Right, the "D" column in this example.  I intend for this ledger to run for an entire year nonstop.  So, I would want my "expense total" and "income total" cells to sum the entire column no matter how many rows there are.

Comment: Move `Income`, `Expense` and `Balance` from cell D18, 19, 20 to say F1,2 and 3 and simply adjust the formulas accordingly. For example D18 formula in F1 becomes `=SUMIF(C:C,"Income",D:D)`. Similarly for the other.

Comment: Having trouble with the conditional formatting to cause expense numbers to be red and income numbers to be green.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=IF(transaction_type_cell_address="income",...,IF(transaction_type_cell_address="expense",...))
```